# Has anyone combined org-sidebar with org-panes? (persistent location & automatically in buffers)

Tags: org-mode, window, side-bar

In my ideal world, every org file could automatically open with a small sidebar always showing where I am, [similar to how Typora works](https://typora.io/img/new/outline.webm), which allows you to select other locations to go to. I'm trying to understand if a package (or package fork) to do this exists. Or any other way to accomplish this goal?

[org-panes](https://github.com/knupfer/org-panes) has several useful qualities:

1. Showing you in "sidebars" where you are at all times in a the "main" org buffer.
2. Simply bringing you to a particular point in the main buffer when a "sidebar" headline is selected.
3. Automatically enabling and disabling "sidebars" as you enter and leave the main buffer (updating the "sidebars" as you switch between org files).

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any way to really disable the extra "contents" buffer.

[org-sidebar](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-sidebar) is much more configurable in useful ways (e.g. in selecting what is visible). However, it doesn't seem to do any of the above, and narrows to a particular headline instead of just moving to it.

Has anyone added `org-panes` style functionality to `org-sidebar`? ( 
Or in lieu of that, just remove the content buffer? (I've been surprised to see more generally, that it seems there is no standard way of creating sidebars in emacs that associate with files or filetypes. Perhaps I'm missing something?) Or is there another package that fulfills these criteria?

Comment: The question isn't clear. Are you really asking whether anyone has done this? Or are you asking how to do it? Or are you asking how to automatically open an Org file with a sidebar that shows where you are? And please specify what you mean by adding `org-panes` style functionality to `org-sidebar`.